# Unity Key Press to Start and Stop

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I'm not sure what I'm missing in my code here, could someone help? I'm wanting to press Space to start the Blink function repeating (plus some other things, obviously), then press Space again to Stop and continue on to a different State. With the code below, pressing Space will start the Blink function repeating, but pressing Space again does nothing.

```
    private bool isDown = false;

void Update () {
    if(Input.GetKeyDown (KeyCode.Space)) {
    if (isDown) {
        CancelInvoke("Blink");
        SetState (LightStates.GREEN);
        isDown = false; 
        }
    else {
        SetState (LightStates.OFF);
        GameObject.Find ("GreenLight").GetComponent<Renderer>().material.color = Color.grey;
        InvokeRepeating ("Blink", 0f, 0.1f);
        isDown = true; 
        }
    }
}
```

EDIT: Perhaps my use of the word "button" was misinterpreted. I appreciate the coroutine suggestion, but I am looking to find out how to start a function on a key press and stop the action on a key press of the same key. Changing the function to a coroutine didn't get this to work as I still don't know how to implement the key press to start/stop the coroutine.

The end result is the same. Pressing the Space key starts the action and pressing it again does nothing.

```
bool isBlinking = false;
IEnumerator blinkCoroutine;

Renderer yellowLight;

void Start()
{
    blinkCoroutine = blinkCOR();

    //CACHE THE Renderer COMPONENT 
    yellowLight = GameObject.Find("YellowLight").GetComponent<Renderer>()
}

void Update() {
    if (Input.GetKeyDown (KeyCode.Space) && !isBlinking) { 
        BlinkStart();
    } else if (Input.GetKeyDown (KeyCode.Space) && isBlinking) {
        BlinkStop();
    }
}

IEnumerator blinkCOR()
{
    SetState (LightStates.OFF);

    //Everything in the while loop will be called every frame until stopped
    while (true)
    {
        yellowLight.material.color = Color.Lerp(Color.grey, Color.yellow, Mathf.PingPong(Time.time, 1));
        //Wait for the next frame
        yield return null;
    }
}

void BlinkStart()
{
    if (!isBlinking)
    {
        isBlinking = true;
        StartCoroutine(blinkCoroutine);
    }
}

void BlinkStop()
{
    if (isBlinking)
    {
        StopCoroutine(blinkCoroutine);
        isBlinking = false;

        //Restore old state
        SetState (LightStates.GREEN);
    }
}
```

EDIT: Full code. This is a state machine that switches the traffic light colors on a timer. When in LightStates.RED, user should be able to press space to turn off all "lights" and have the yellow light blink from grey to yellow. When pressing space again, the state machine should restart with the green "light" in StateGreen function.

```
using UnityEngine;
using System;
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;

public class TrafficLightScriptMachine : MonoBehaviour {

private TrafficLight trafficLight;
private LightStates curState = LightStates.OFF;
private Dictionary<LightStates, Action> dic = new Dictionary<LightStates, Action>();

private bool isDown = false;
bool isBlinking = false;
IEnumerator blinkCoroutine;

// Use this for initialization
void Start () {

    trafficLight = GetComponent<TrafficLight>();
    dic.Add (LightStates.OFF, new Action (StateOff));
    dic.Add (LightStates.RED, new Action (StateRed));
    dic.Add (LightStates.YELLOW, new Action (StateYellow));
    dic.Add (LightStates.GREEN, new Action (StateGreen));

    SetState (LightStates.RED);
    blinkCoroutine = blinkCOR();

    GameObject.Find ("GreenLight").GetComponent<Renderer>().material.color = Color.grey;
    GameObject.Find ("RedLight").GetComponent<Renderer>().material.color = Color.grey;
    GameObject.Find ("YellowLight").GetComponent<Renderer>().material.color = Color.grey;


}



// Update is called once per frame
void Update () {

    dic[curState].Invoke();


        if (curState == LightStates.RED && Input.GetKeyDown (KeyCode.Space) && !isBlinking) { 
            BlinkStart();
        } else if (Input.GetKeyDown (KeyCode.Space) && isBlinking) {
            BlinkStop();
        }
}

IEnumerator blinkCOR()
{
    SetState (LightStates.OFF);
    while (true)
    {

        GameObject.Find ("GreenLight").GetComponent<Renderer>().material.color = Color.grey;
        GameObject.Find ("YellowLight").GetComponent<Renderer>().material.color = Color.Lerp(Color.grey, Color.yellow, Mathf.PingPong(Time.time, 1));
        //Wait for the next frame
        yield return null;
    }
}

void BlinkStart()
{
    if (!isBlinking)
    {
        isBlinking = true;
        StartCoroutine(blinkCoroutine);
    }
}

void BlinkStop()
{
    if (isBlinking)
    {
        StopCoroutine(blinkCoroutine);
        isBlinking = false;
        SetState (LightStates.GREEN);
    }
}

public enum LightStates
{
    OFF,
    RED,
    YELLOW,
    GREEN,

    NUM_STATES
}

public void StateRed ()
{
    // if the time passed since reset is greater than the red switch time then switch to yellow state
    if ((trafficLight.GetLightTime()) > (trafficLight.GetRedLight()))
    {
        GameObject.Find ("GreenLight").GetComponent<Renderer>().material.color = Color.grey;
        GameObject.Find ("RedLight").GetComponent<Renderer>().material.color = Color.red;
        // switch to yellow state
        SetState (LightStates.YELLOW);
        trafficLight.ResetTimeSinceLastTransition();
    }
}

public void StateYellow ()
{
    // If the time since the last light transition is greater than the time to stay yellow, transition to green
    if ((trafficLight.GetLightTime()) > (trafficLight.GetYellowLight()))
    {
        GameObject.Find ("RedLight").GetComponent<Renderer>().material.color = Color.grey;
        GameObject.Find ("YellowLight").GetComponent<Renderer>().material.color = Color.yellow;
        // switch to green state
        SetState (LightStates.GREEN);
        trafficLight.ResetTimeSinceLastTransition();
    }
}

public void StateGreen ()
{
    // If the time since the last light transition is greater than the time to stay green, transition to red.
    if ((trafficLight.GetLightTime()) > (trafficLight.GetGreenLight()))
    {
        GameObject.Find ("YellowLight").GetComponent<Renderer>().material.color = Color.grey;
        GameObject.Find ("GreenLight").GetComponent<Renderer>().material.color = Color.green;
        SetState (LightStates.RED);
        trafficLight.ResetTimeSinceLastTransition();
    }
}

public void StateOff ()
{
    gameObject.GetComponent<Renderer>().material.color = Color.grey;
}

public void SetState (LightStates newState)
{
    curState = newState; 
}

}
```

Comment: The duplication question is doing almost the-same thing. Using a `boolean` variable is good sometimes but there are times when coroutines should be used and this is one of those times. Start and Stop coroutine when button is pressed. See accepted answer for implementation.

Comment: The end result of doing this is the same as what I had before. Pressing the key starts the action and pressing it again does nothing.

Comment: It's still the-same thing. All you have to do is replace the Button stuff with the Keypress. You were almost close. Just replace the `Start` function  with the `Update` function.  Also do the blinking in the coroutine function **not** with the the `InvokeRepeating` function. If you show your `Blink` function and explain what it is doing and what else you have to do when the key is pressed I can modify your code to show you how to do that. I modified your second code to show you what you should be doing.

Comment: Also, `blinnkCoroutine = blinkCOR();` should be done in the `Start` function. See the edit in your question.

Comment: Okay, I made an edit to include what the Blink function is doing. It's still giving the same issue. Everything works except pressing the key to stop.

Comment: Oh, and what I'm trying to do with the code: Press space to make YellowLight blink between yellow and grey. Then press space to stop blinking and go into LightStates.GREEN.

Comment: Change the state inside the `BlinkStop` function and also if it is blinking. Check my edit. Also, notice how I cached the YellowLight `renderer` so that you don't have to use `GameObject.Find` and `GetComponent` every frame. If this does not work, tell me what exactly you expect yo happen when you press the stop key. All I know now is that state should change to `LightStates.GREEN` when stop is pressed.

Comment: I edited to add the full code. Hopefully, that will help. I thought that only giving relevant code would be easier. I didn't implement the changes to avoid GameObject.Find yet, but that's super helpful. I will do that at the end.

Comment: Np. I expect your code is now working...

Comment: This part is definitely working, yes. I appreciate the help and implementation of this the right way.